# Are there models that can make prediction based on fixed value of a variable?

Tags: r, time-series, prediction

So I am making a time series analysis and even though packages like Prophet are good at it, I want to know how a certain value can change the prediction.

For instance, I want to know how high the sales will be if I set the value of discount variable to 0.2 in my future data frame for the next month, but it seems like Prophet isn't good in that.

Are there any recommendations which model would be the best to do this?

I am writing my code in R

Comment: You should be looking for a book on time series analysis, not software.

Comment: analysis of sensitivity? search in the package list

Answer (score 0):

Indeed here below is a simple way of doing an analysis of sensitivity, using a simulation since some forecasting methods have a random component and won't always return the same result. Using the forecast package, assuming you'd like to know how much the forecast varies for 10 periods in the future when the last element of a vector x varies from +-1:

```
x <- c(1:100)+rnorm(10,0,1)
plot(x, t="l")
require(fpp)
fc <- forecast(x)
plot(fc)
fcx <- fc$mean
# simulation
deltas <- c()
for(i in 1:10) {
 y <- x
 y[100] <- x[100]+1*(-1^i)
 fcy <- forecast(y)$mean
 deltas <- c(deltas, abs(fcy[10]-fcx[10]))
}
sentitivity <- mean(deltas)
```

Here the sensitivity I get is about 0.01445129, this is the absolute variation of the forecast 10 periods ahead when the 100th element of x varies from +-1. You can add a second loop through all your parameters of interest.